# Matlab alternative function for ClustOfVar from R

Tags: r, matlab

I am working on clustering of variables in matlab. Two functions come in ClustOfVar package in R, called `hcluster()` and `cutreevar()`.

I am good in Matlab and would like to use alternatives of `hcluster()` and `cutreevar()` in it.

Does Matlab has any inbuilt function which computes exactly same as `hcluster()` and `cutreevar()` does in R?

Need help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for heirarchical clustering you'll probably want to look at [`clusterdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/clusterdata.html). Note that you'll need the statistical toolbox for this function.

Comment: Here I am looking for loading factor for each variable in each cluster and scores of each cluster for each observations. How Matlab does it?